# MySQL show grouped results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, having

I have the following snippet of a table:

```
 stamp   | group  | value
 123     | 1      | 4
 124     | 2      | 5
 124     | 2      | 6
 125     | 4      | 7
 125     | 4      | 8
 125     | 5      | 9
```

I can't seem to find a query that gives me this result:

```
 stamp   | value1  | value2
 124     | 5       | 6
 125     | 7       | 8
 125     | 9       | null
```

So basically, all results with the same stamp are shown, grouped by 'group'.
Is this possible ? I've tried to accomplish this with subqueries, 'group by' and 'having' statements, but I can't seem to find the right query..

Thnx in advance !

Comment: There is only one 123, so i don't really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select stamp, 
       SUBSTR(`values`,1,INSTR(`values`,',')-1) as value1,
       NULLIF(TRIM(',' FROM SUBSTR(`values`,INSTR(`values`,',')+1)),'') as value2,
       `values`
FROM
(
SELECT stamp, `group`,CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) ,',') AS `values`
FROM stamps
GROUP BY stamp, `group`
) aggr
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/88a2e/10)

This works only when every group has <=2 rows only.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this, more or less:

```
SELECT stamp, `group`, GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) AS `values`
FROM stamps
GROUP BY stamp, `group`
```

The key is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Based on your data the output will be

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| stamp | group | values |
+-------+-------+--------+
|   123 |     1 | 4      |
|   124 |     2 | 5,6    |
|   125 |     4 | 7,8    |
|   125 |     5 | 9      |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Great answer ! With the extra tweaking from Ravisankar, this is the perfect answer. Thanks !